# How can I pick one row from an array at random?

Tags: c#, arrays

When my application starts up I do this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

I then have this code that create a list of phrases. What I would like to do is to select the PhraseId of just one of the rows in that list. I am trying with rand but getting very confused about how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

```
var phrases = App.selectedPhrases.All.Where(x => x.Points > 1).ToList();
if (phrases.Count == 0) return;
var indx = (int)rand.Next(phrases.Count) + 1;
var id = phrases[indx].PhraseId;
```

Can someone confirm for me, is this the correct way to do it and will it work no matter how many rows are in the list and if there is just one element will it pick that or should I code differently for that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change

```
var indx = (int)rand.Next(phrases.Count) + 1;
```

to:

```
var indx = rand.Next(phrases.Count);
```

> 0 <= rand.Next(phrases.Count) < phrases.Count

as index stars from 0 but `+ 1`  in `rand.Next(phrases.Count) + 1`  would exclude 0 index and would include `indx == phrases.Count` which is out of range.

Comment: Ahhh thats better, you had me scratching my head there for a second

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah i made a mistake I just woke up, i'm still sleepy ;)

Comment: So if the count was 1 then it would always pick the 0 element of the array?

Comment: @Alan2 yes, the random has no other choice